# I don't understand the meaning of a line,

Tags: sentence-meaning

Currently reading [**this**](https://www.yahoo.com/gma/marijuana-sales-illinois-top-3m-first-day-legal-164504388--abc-news-topstories.html), the 3rd paragraph says,

> "Launching the legalization of cannabis in a way that includes communities left behind for far too long, creates good jobs and **expunges thousands of records for those who have lost out on opportunities** and ends prohibition," Toi Hutchinson, senior adviser to the governor for cannabis control, said. "Today is a historic new day, and as we move forward with growing this industry, I thank all those who worked hard to make the launch a success and will continue to dedicate themselves to expanding opportunities and righting the wrongs of the past."

I am very sorry I don't understand the bold line. I would like to thank you for your follow ups with my resent questions, but I am happy should anyone generously
explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a very long sentence. It contains a *list* of items, but it isn't punctuated very well.

It essentially says:

> Launching the legalization of cannabis in a way that includes communities left behind for far too long:
>
> - creates good jobs
> - expunges thousands of records for those who have lost out on opportunities
> - ends prohibition.

"Expunging records" and "ending prohibition" are therefore two different points. The "records" it is speaking about are *criminal records* - a common abbreviation (eg "*he's got a record*"). Persons with a criminal record may be denied some opportunities - in some places they cannot vote, and they may be restricted from certain kinds of employment. This may be the "opportunities" referred to.

The writer evidently believes that decriminalisation of cannabis will achieve these three points.

Comment: Could you please enlighten me about what "**lost out on opportunity**" means more kindly? Sorry and thank you.

Comment: @KentaroDonatesForMonica added detail.

Comment: Thank your for the elaboration.

Comment: People with a drug conviction cannot get a visa to enter the USA and many other countries; I suppose this might be seen as an opportunity that somebody might 'lose out' on.